# Undefine variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, local-variables

Let's say I'm using `irb`, and type `a = 5`. How do I remove the definition of `a` so that typing `a` returns a `NameError`?

Some context: later I want to do this:

```
context = Proc.new{}.binding
context.eval 'a = 5'
context.eval 'undef a'  # though this doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are [remove_class_variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-remove_class_variable), [remove_instance_variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-remove_instance_variable) and [remove_const](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) methods but there is currently no equivalent for local variables.

Comment: hmm, annoying that there aren't any methods like that. I guess I can stick to instance variables for now.

Comment: Those links don't look like they are going to the right place anymore.

Comment: @jcollum thanks. `remove_instance_variable` and `remove_const` are private methods so don't seem to be included in the documentation on ruby-doc.org any more. I've updated the answer to use equivalent links to apidock.com

Answer (score 29):

You can avoid un-declaring the variable by reducing the scope in which the variable exists:

```
def scope 
  yield
end

scope do 
  b = 1234
end

b  # undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
```

Comment: This is the answer I wanted to see.

Comment: there is an standard kind of `scope` function called `Proc.new`: `Proc.new { b = 1 } ; b`

Comment: Worth noting that `Proc.new` differs from the given `scope` in that it doesn't actually call the block. The equivalent would be `Proc.new { b = 1 }.call; b`. You can also use `lambda { b = 1 }.call`.

Answer (score 15):

You can always 'clear' irb's registry of local variables by invoking an irb subshell. Think of how Bash shells work with respect to unexported environment variables. Since you metioned interactive mode, this solution ought to work for that.

As far as production code, I wouldn't want to undefine local variables as part of a solution - keyed hashes would probably be better for that type of scenario.

Here's what I mean:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> a = "a"
=> "a"
irb(main):002:0> defined? a
=> "local-variable"
irb(main):003:0> irb # step into subshell with its own locals
irb#1(main):001:0> defined? a
=> nil
irb#1(main):002:0> a
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
    from /Users/dean/.irbrc:108:in `method_missing'
    from (irb#1):2
irb#1(main):003:0> exit
=> #<IRB::Irb: @context=#<IRB::Context:0x1011b48b8>, @signal_status=:IN_EVAL, @scanner=#<RubyLex:0x1011b3df0>>
irb(main):004:0> a # now we're back and a exists again
=> "a"
```

Comment: that returns: "`NotImplementedError: ruby engine can initialize only in the main thread`"

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of the question, you could limit the variable to a scope, assuming you are okay with other local variables being locked to the same scope. This is useful particularly if you are defining something in a class and don't want the local variable to stay around in the class declaration.

The only ways I can think to do this is with `Integer#times` or `Array#each` like so:

```
1.times do |a|
  a = 5
  # code…
end

[5].each do |a|
  # code…
end
```

There are probably other, even cleaner ways to limit to a block besides this. These aren't as clean as I'd like and I'd love to see if someone has a cleaner method to use to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Currently you have no mean to remove global variables, local variables and class variables. You can remove constants using "remove_const" method though

Comment: Not true for class variables - there is remove_class_variable.