# How can I unset a variable in Ruby or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Undefine variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011654/undefine-variable-in-ruby)

In php I could do the following:

```
    $myVariable = 'foo';
    echo $myVariable;
    unset( $myVariable );
```

How can I do basically the same thing in ruby land?

Answer (score -7):

You can assign it nil value.
Example:
  your_variable = "yourname"
Now, when you want to 'unset' it, you could do
  your_variable = nil

Comment: I assume this will free the memory in the same manner as php?

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Assigning nil to a variable is not the same as undeclaring it.

Comment: When the garbage collector comes around and sees nothing referencing the given object/variable, it will be released. There's no way to manually force it to release.

Comment: What about GC.start ? I looks like I could set the variable to nil then start garbage collection ?

Comment: @Jakcst Setting a variable to nil is still defined in the object space. The garbage collector should mark all variables out of scope for garbage collection, although, I find that making system calls sometimes does not release memory.

Comment: Setting the variable return `nil` and not `NameError: undefined local variable or method`. When variable is deleted it should raise `NameError`.